# Flutter ShaderMask using an ImageShader

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get a `ShaderMask` that uses an Image as a Shader. I'm reading the image from memory, so my image is a `File`. How do I create an ImageShader using an image from memory?

```
File imageFile;
Image image = Image.file(imageFile)

ShaderMask(
   shaderCallback: (bounds) {
      Float64List matrix4 = new Matrix4.identity().storage; // <--- DO I NEED THIS OR THE BOUNDS?
      return ImageShader(image, TileMode.mirror, TileMode.mirror, matrix4);
   },
   child: child
)
```

There's an error with `ImageShader` as image is the wrong type (I need ui.Image, which I don't understand how to create).

**How do I create the `ImageShader` from a `File` image?**

PS: is `matrix4` correct or should I use the bounds somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to know is that `ImageShader` uses an Image from the `dart:ui` package and not an instance of the `Image` widget. There is no direct operation or constructor available to create an instance of `ui.Image` from a network location, a file or asset, so you need some code to get it done.

The best generic solution i came up with after looking up many resources and digging into the code how the `Image` widget is loading raw images, is to use an `ImageProvider` as source. The abstract `ImageProvider` has implementations like `NetworkImage`, `FileImage`, `ExactAssetImage` and `MemoryImage` to load your image from any resource you want.

First you get an `ImageStream` using the `ImageProvider.resolve` method. The `resolve` method takes an argument of type `ImageConfiguration`, that should be filled with as many information as you have available at the code location. You can use the global `createLocalImageConfiguration` function in most cases, but be aware that this will not work when you create the shader in the `initState` method of a StatefulWidget.

On the resolved `ImageStream` you can attach an `ImageStreamListener`, that takes an `ImageListener` callback as first parameter. Once the image is loaded, the callback will be called with an `ImageInfo`, which provides the requested image on the `image` property.

You can construct the `ImageShader` with both tile modes as `TileMode.clamp` and a simple identity matrix, which you can either create by hand or take that one offered by the `Matrix4` class. If you need the image shader to be smaller than the size of the provided image, you can wrap your provider in an `ResizeProvider` and specify the desired width and height.

Below my implementation of an `ImageMask` widget as a reference, which can be used to mask widgets of any kind.

```
class ImageMask extends StatefulWidget {
  final ImageProvider image;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Widget child;

  const ImageMask({@required this.image, this.width, this.height, @required this.child});

  @override
  _ImageMaskState createState() => _ImageMaskState();
}

class _ImageMaskState extends State<ImageMask> {
  Future<Shader> _shader;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _shader = _loadShader(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _shader,
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<Shader> snapshot) {
        return snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done || snapshot.hasError
            ? SizedBox(width: widget.width, height: widget.height)
            : ShaderMask(
                blendMode: BlendMode.dstATop,
                shaderCallback: (bounds) => snapshot.data,
                child: widget.child,
              );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<Shader> _loadShader(BuildContext context) async {
    final completer = Completer<ImageInfo>();

    // use the ResizeImage provider to resolve the image in the required size
    ResizeImage(widget.image, width: widget.width.toInt(), height: widget.height.toInt())
        .resolve(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(widget.width, widget.height)))
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((info, _) => completer.complete(info)));

    final info = await completer.future;
    return ImageShader(
      info.image,
      TileMode.clamp,
      TileMode.clamp,
      Float64List.fromList(Matrix4.identity().storage),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question but still if someone's looking for the answer then there's an easy workaround which is using a third party package [widget_mask](https://pub.dev/packages/widget_mask)

```
WidgetMask(
  blendMode: BlendMode.difference,
  mask: Center(
    child: Text(
      'Negative',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 50,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: Image.asset('images/my_image.jpg'),
);
```